# How to use MultiFileUploadField in wicket for multiplfe file selection?

Tags: java, file-upload, wicket

I want to use Multiple file selection in uploading files. I do not know how could i achieve this. I'm using apache wicket 1.4.9 and please suggest me on how to do.

Thanks
G Samrat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple file upload is an HTML5 feature. Wicket supports that only in versions 1.5 and up. You need to upgrade to do this.

In 1.5 you use a regular `FileUploadField`, which will now give you a `List<FileUpload>` instead  of just a single `FileUpload`. In your markup you put `<input type="file" multiple="multiple"/>`. The rest is as usual.

Besides, 1.4.9 is *ancient*. Even if you decide to stay with 1.4.x you really should upgrade to the latest 1.4.x version at least, for many bugfixes, including some relevant to security.